# Active directory account lockout monitoring

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, monitoring

I am trying to monitor number of account lockout every 30sec. Powershell script/cmdlet should only the number of lockout.

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
(Search-ADAccount -LockedOut -Server YourDomainController.Domain.loc | Measure-Object).Count
```

You have to Call

> Import-Module ActiveDirectory

only once, the second line can repeated as much as you need it.